# PHP new Session id gets regenerate instead of using existing session after redirection

Tags: php, laravel, session, apache2, php-7

I have one page called page1.php which set certain variables and redirects to payment gateway site like below:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var1'] = "test1";
$_SESSION['var2'] = "test2";
$_SESSION['var3'] = "test3";
header('Location: http://www.paypal.com');
exit();
?>
```

And after successful payment user redirects to success.php where I am trying to get value from session variable like below. But it gets empty randomly. From logs I found that session id got changed after redirection. Any idea why it is generating new session id on redirection for some random case only?

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

From logs I had found that a new session id gets generated on success.php when I get empty session. As issue is not reproducible easily and it happens randomly, Is anyone have any solution or suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: Where is the php session stored? Show me the configuration about session storage.

Comment: We are storing sessions in Redis

Comment: Have you check configuration for consistency ?

Comment: Which configuration should I check and verify? I have below configuration set for session:
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = “tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx?persistent=1&timeout=1&database=0”

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php or paste output of `phpinfo()`;

Comment: I have below configuration set for session: session.save_handler = redis session.save_path = “tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx?persistent=1&timeout=1&database=0”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201707/discussion-between-gasol-and-krunal).

Comment: I have something similar for registration mails. When the user clicks on the link in the mail, then new session id is generated with empty session after redirect. When they copy-paste the link to the address bar, then an already existing session id is used and it is not regenerated after redirect. I have no idea what causes this behavior, it does not make sense and took me 4 days to narrow down to this code. I generally hate this kind of bugs, when PHP fails, not my code, because I never write tests for things, that suppose to work out of the box and they take a shitload of time to debug.